# General bit counting

Tags: algorithm, bit-manipulation

I'm aware of is this fairly nice solution for counting the number set bits in an integer:

```
CountBits(n)    
    count = 0
    while n > 0
        n ← n & (n - 1)
        count ← count + 1
```

Is there a similarly elegant solution of counting how many non-overlapping k bit groups are non-zero. I currently have:

```
CountGroups(n, k)
    count = 0
    mask = (2 << k) - 1
    while n > 0
        if n & mask ≠ 0
            count ← count + 1
        n >> k
```

which is linear in the position of the left most group. In the latter algorithm, if only the first and last groups are set, I have to visit and check all the groups in between, while the former only performs two operations regardless. It's not a bottleneck or anything, just curious if there is a better way.

Comment: First make it right: n>>k in first trunk of branch, n>>1 in the other trunk.

Comment: What? Could you elaborate?

Comment: The bit group of k bits can start at any offset -- not necessarily at multiples of k?

Comment: Oh I see, in general yes. But in my specific application, no. The integers were created by summing smaller integers shifted by increasing multiples of k, starting with 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One can calculate groups of k set bits in parallel by splitting the word to odd and even sequences. Adding one to each group, *carries* to the next empty position (marked with ...) if and only if all bits in the group were set.

The original question is about *any bit is set in a group*, but this can be transformed by complementing *n*, adding one, and complementing the result. (Now result == 1 if and only if the original group was all zeroes.)

```
 // ...xxx...xxx...xxx   even sequence
 // yyy...yyy...yyy...   odd sequence

 uint64_t a = ~n & even_mask;         // inverse of n
 uint64_t b = (~n >> k) & even_mask;  // inverse of n
 a += 0010101;  // this is octal, where a "one" is added to each group
 b += 0010101;  // same for odd sequence

 //  a = 001xxx000yyy001xxx  -- e.g. first and last group were all ones
 //  b = 000yyy000yyy001yyy  -- e.g. last group of 'y' was all one

 a &= ~even_mask;   // remove the xxx yyy parts, leaving only carry
 b &= ~even_mask;
 a |= (b << 1);
 return bitcount(a ^ 03030303);   // return total number of carry bits
```

Bitcount can be done in parallel, with special instruction if available (__popcount) or with the Kerningham Richie -method (n & (n-1)) as described.

This only illustrates k==3, but can be extended for arbitrary k, even though the return of interest diminishes when k grows larger.

---

Depending on *k* there might be better algorithm to just derive a boolean expression for the condition.

In this case for each group the condition is n(i) | n(i+1) | ... n(i+k-1), which can be evaluated in parallel and/or using a folding technique, which is especially powerful when k is a power of 2

```
//  n = aabb ccdd eeff gghh iijj   -- original sequence, k = 4
//      0011 0011 0011 0011 0011   -- mask
n = (n | (n >> 2)) & 0x33333333;   // fold to aa|bb, cc|dd, etc.
n = (n | (n >> 1)) & 0x11111111;   // fold boolean expression as 0th bit position in each group

return bitcount(n);
```

Comment: This is cool, I'll have to look at it more throughly tomorrow morning. Only thing, and maybe I wasn't specific enough, but I'm interested in counting all non-zero groups, not just the "all ones" groups.

Comment: I originally answered "all k bits are set", but revised it to "at least one bit is set", whose complement is "no bits are set". Thus `a ^ 030303 /* octal */` complements the result.

Comment: @DezmondGoff, if you think this by Aki answered your question, consider to mark it as the solution by clicking on the checkmark. Also, a thumbs up wouldn't be wrong.

Comment: @Herb I would have done it sooner, but I was waiting to see if anyone else had different ideas.